# Why aren't the offchain views appearing?

Tags: smart-contracts, smartpy, taquito, tzip16

I'm extending the smartpy FA2 template

```
# 
FA2 = sp.import_script_from_url("https://smartpy.io/dev/templates/FA2.py")
class TezosLandNft(FA2.FA2):
...
```

which has the following offchain views defined

```
# ex:
class FA2_token_metadata(FA2_core):
    @sp.offchain_view(pure = True)
    def token_metadata(self, tok):
...
```

However, when querying for these views using taquito, none of the offchain_views are appearing

```
const token_contract = await Tezos.wallet.at(WALLET_ADDRESS, compose(tzip12, tzip16));
const views = await token_contract.tzip16().metadataViews()
# views === {}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is caused by an invalid IPFS link.

**Steps to FIX the issue:**

1. Update the metadata (including views, etc...)
   [image]
2. Copy the generated JSON
   [image]
3. Upload the metadata JSON to IPFS

You can use [Pinata](https://pinata.cloud) for this.

4. Update the metadata link in the code

Replace all occurences of `sp.metadata_of_url("https://example.com")` with `sp.metadata_of_url("<ipfs_link>")`

Comment: That did it. Thanks for step by step instructions!