# Best way to create FA1.2 token with TZIP016

Tags: smartpy, fa1.2, tzip16

What is the best way to implement a FA1.2 token with TZIP-016 metadata (symbol, name, decimals...)?
I am using SmartPy.
So far, I noted two methods:
the first one is to implement a FA1.2 token with a json metadata such as

```
{
  "name": "mytoken",
  "description": "This is constructed just to be an example to be put on IPFS.\nAt the time of writing, the TZIP is now at `30b4bd3` a.k.a. “WIP-TZIP-16: Mention future work & extensions.”",
  "version": "0.42",
  "decimals": 42,
  "symbol": "AAAA",
  "interfaces": [
    "TZIP-16 draft"
  ]
}
```

By there is also a method where people:
Implement a FA2 token that generates the desired FA1.2 token with a method called :

```
make_metadata(symbol, name, decimals):
    "Helper function to build metadata JSON bytes values."
     return (sp.map(l = {
        # Remember that michelson wants map already in ordered
        "decimals" : sp.bytes_of_string("%d" % decimals),
        "name" : sp.bytes_of_string(name),
        "symbol" : sp.bytes_of_string(symbol)
     }))
```

What is the best method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The FA1.2 template was updated this week by Keefer Taylor. It will be updated in https://smartpy.io templates this weekend.

Template link: https://smartpy.io/ide?cid=Qma5v9x6xjbzB82hjhr5Y5Sw2oppRzhyNBN11eVVyXpvxv&k=ea98e1d25d85d92f75c7

Here is an example after deployment: https://tzcomet.io/#/explorer%3Fexplorer-input%3DKT1RbbpEXYbjJx3pB5QxsCrcoBthXa3vMLoa

You can use the `sp.init_metadata` helper to generate valid metadata to be used off-chain or encoded to bytes and stored in the contract storage.
https://smartpy.io/reference.html#_metadata_support

This thread contains a guide for that: [Why aren't the offchain views appearing?](https://tezos.stackexchange.com/questions/3328/why-arent-the-offchain-views-appearing)

Comment: This work is not finished (and probably shouldn't be used like that). Some better template will be provided eventually.